# Get count of post in WordPress Depend on meta value

Tags: wordpress

I need to get count of post that have same meta value "date_submission".

Example:

if i have 10 post in date_submission "15 February، 2018 2:26 pm", echo message " The post is not empty".

I try this :

```
function rtb_booking_check() {
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->posts = $wpdb->prefix.'posts';

$result_booking_meta = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) from $wpdb->posts , $wpdb->postmeta where post_type='rtb-booking' and post_status='confirmed' and $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ");
    return $result_booking_meta;

}
```

Above code return me count of post, but i need add condition, have same date_submission

the meta data in database save like :

```
a:5:{s:5:"party";i:1;s:5:"email";s:17:"kam@kam.sa";s:5:"phone";s:11:"05922165447";s:15:"date_submission";i:1518627125;s:2:"ip";s:3:"::1";}
```

any help

Comment: you might need some `and date_submission=1518627125` - a filtering claus, that determine what to look for - you already have some of them - so it should be no trouble to add an extra `WHERE` claus

Comment: i cannot add date_submission in query ! the date_submission not a row in table ,,, its meta value http://prntscr.com/if5114

Comment: in the codex - it looks like you can- https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query#The_query

Comment: ok i see i can add 'AND $wpdb->posts.post_date', but how can check the post have same date ?!!

Comment: I was thinking about `AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'date_submission' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '1518627125' `

Comment: this value '1518627125' store in table so how can check!!